# Key of children required based on self length > 1

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an rules array, that contains rules. Theses rules need to be groupped (groupId) if they are more than 1.

```
"rules": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": { "$ref": "#/rule" }
},

"rule": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["keepValue"],
    "properties": {
      "groupId": { "type": ["number", "string"] },
      "keepValue": { "type": "boolean" }
    }
```

When `rules.length > 1` I want `groupId` to be **mandatory**. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if`/`then` keywords for the conditional and `minItems` for the array length assertion.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2
  },
  "then": {
    "items": { "required": ["groupId"] }
  }
}
```